# What is the function on the cover of this journal of complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the function on the cover of this journal of complex analysis?

[image]

Comment: It appears to be a colored Julia set, with a high-quality version of the stock image available here: https://www.canstockphoto.com/art-deco-julia-fractal-0865869.html

Comment: Regarding the specific choices of zoom, coordinates, and function with which one generates the image, I would imagine only the creator of the image would possibly know (being a chaotic fractal, it's too sensitive on initial conditions to get much from it visually)